# Checking if property exists in object in JavaScript (browser compliance)

Tags: javascript

What is the most standards and best browser compatibility for checking if a given property of an object exists in JavaScript?

I can think of the following:

**1.**

```
if(window && 'navigator' in window && 'userAgent' in window.navigator) {}
```

**2.**

```
if(window && window.navigator && window.navigator.userAgent) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `window &&` check at the start of each of the checks is unnecessary. There's never a natural case where that will evaluate to false. (If you run the code in Nodejs or in a web worker where the `window` global isn't present, then the line will throw an exception, and not evaluate to false. There's no environment where `window &&` will improve things, and having that there is misleading.)

#1 will check whether the `window` object has a `navigator` property with any value, etc. #2 will check whether the `window` object has a `navigator` property with a truthy value. Unless you expect `window.navigator` or `window.navigator.userAgent` to be present as properties but be set to `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, or `''` (which those specific properties aren't ever naturally in browsers), then #2 will work just fine and it's nicely shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Both are completely standard and fully supported. Go with `2` because it is the most commonly used, is shorter, and (not that it matters) was supported since the inception of javascript, whereas `1` came along in ES3.

See MDN for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: A good cavet though, if the prop value could ever be `0` should use `in` since `0` would return false, though that is the value of the prop.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I'm so used to not writing code this way when specifically looking for a falsey value. The caveat applies conversely to `1` if you still want to reject falsey values that happen to be on the object. For example, `'a' in {a: undefined} => true`. There's rarely a one size fits all solution in javascript.